# I need guidance to solve my JavaScript problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

Create a function called 'bigOrSmall' that takes in one parameter, 'arr', which will be an array of numbers. Inside of the bigOrSmall function, create a new array called 'answers'. Then, loop over the passed in arr parameter, and check to see if the number in the array is GREATER than 100. If it is, push 'big' as a string to the answers array. If the number is LESS than or EQUAL to 100, push 'small' as a string to the answers array. Return the answers array inside of the function.

This is what I have so far.

```
function bigOrSmall(answers) {
    for(let i = 0; i > 100; i++) {
        return answers('big')
        if(let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            return answers('small')
        }
        answers(arr[i])
    }
    return answers,
}
```

Obviously I know I'm not doing something right, because it is failing the test, but I want to know if I'm on the right track & to get some tips to get me into the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you should revisit `if` and `for` syntax. `if(let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {` is confusing the two. Your outer loop should iterate over the array, so break the problem into multiple steps: (1) how to iterate over the array? (2) how to add a condition inside the loop to check the current array index against a condition? (3) how to push the outcome of this condition onto a result array. `return answers('big')`  would immediately end the function on the first iteration of the loop. But the loop won't run since the condition is always false. Hope this helps.

Comment: The first problem is that a loop with this header `for(let i = 0; i > 100; i++)` will never run, as `i > 100` is already false the first time through.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop, you use `return` which terminates the function in the first iteration.

You can refactor your code as following:

```js
function bigOrSmall(arr) {
  const answers = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] <= 100) {
      answers.push('small');
    } else {
      answers.push('big');
    }
  }
  return answers
}

console.log(bigOrSmall([0, 105, 100]))
```

Or you can use `Array.map()` to make it one-liner

```js
const mapped = [0,105,100].map(item => item <= 100 ? 'small' : 'big')

console.log(mapped)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot more sense & I totally see what I was doing wrong, of course I need to use the push() method & also .length() method.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it helped. I suggest you to consider using `Array.map()` approach for this kind of operations. It increases readability.

Answer (score 1):

I am really very sorry to say this, but, you're doing almost everything wrong. Now, follow me to the end of the code given below. It'll help you understand how to do things(read the comments very carefully):

```
// defining function bigOrSmall which take parameter 'arr'
function bigOrSmall(arr) { // notice: `arr`
    let answers = []; // declare `answers` array
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // iterate over `arr` array using index
        if(arr[i] > 100) { // if i_th index of `arr` array is greater than 100
            answers.push('big'); // then, push `big`
        } else { // otherwise
            answers.push('small'); // push small
        }
    }
    return answers; // at last return `answers` array
}

let someIntegers = [1, 2, 300, 40, 229, 100]; // declare some input

let ans = bigOrSmall(someIntegers); // pass `someIntegers` in `bigOrSmall` function and capture the returned `answers` array into `ans` variable
// note: `someIntegers` is going to be passed as `arr` inside `bigOrSmall` function

console.log(ans); // print the returned answer
```

The output of the program is:

```
[ 'small', 'small', 'big', 'small', 'big', 'small' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function bigOrSmall(arr) {
     const answer = =[] 
            for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
               if (arr[i] <= 100) {
               answer.push('small)
            } else {
              answer.push('big') 
            }
            return answers,
        }
```

Fisrt, the argument should be an array of number, thats why I wrote (arr),
then you need to declare answer array. Then use the loop to iterate from 0 to the length of the array (your original loop will not stop because it will keep incrementing forever), then compare each number to 100, then push the string in the answer array. You could use map or forEach method also, make it look cleaner

Answer (score 0):

this looks better to me try it out.

```
function bigOrSmall(answers){

      var small = true;
      answers.forEach(item => {
        (item <= 100) ? small = true : false;
      });
      (small == true) ? answers.push('big') : answers.push('small');
      return answers
}
```